How to add Polygon Mesh Processing library to my cmake project with eigen already added
I'm working on a C++ project where I'm already using the Eigen library.
I now want to add library that will allow me to build a surface mesh. I thought about CGAL but it seems to be too heavy and complex for what I need. So I found Polygon Mesh Processing Library or PMP, that will probably do the job just fine.
The problem with the PMP is that it already depends on Eigen (see here).
So when I changed my root CMakeLists.txt to:
# Add Eigen using CPM
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME Eigen
        GITLAB_REPOSITORY libeigen/eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4
        OPTIONS
        "EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF"           # Do not build documentation
        "EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF"     # Optional, disables pkg-config
        "BUILD_TESTING OFF"             # Disable building and running tests
)

# Add PMP library using CPM
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME PMP
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY pmp-library/pmp-library
        GIT_TAG 3.0.0  # Specify the version you need, or leave it out for the latest
)

I got an error
CMake Error at cmake-build-debug/_deps/pmp-src/examples/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "eigen" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is an interface library
  created in source directory.
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.

I'm obviously no CMake expert. Is there a solution to this? Can I convince PMP to use my instance of Eigen? Do I have to find a different meshing library, one independant of Eigen?
Edit:
As suggested by Botje, I fixed my Cmake to:
# Add Eigen using CPM
CPMAddPackage(
        NAME Eigen
        GITLAB_REPOSITORY libeigen/eigen
        GIT_TAG 3.4.0
        OPTIONS
        "EIGEN_BUILD_DOC OFF"           # Do not build documentation
        "EIGEN_BUILD_PKGCONFIG OFF"     # Optional, disables pkg-config
        "BUILD_TESTING OFF"             # Disable building and running tests
)

# Add PMP library using CPM
# Set EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR if it is not already defined
message("${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR}/Eigen")
if (NOT DEFINED EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR}/Eigen")
endif()
find_package(Eigen 3.4.0 REQUIRED)

CPMAddPackage(
        NAME PMP
        GITHUB_REPOSITORY pmp-library/pmp-library
        GIT_TAG 3.0.0  # Specify the version you need, or leave it out for the latest
)


This is for sure a step forward, but I get a new error regarding the paths:
C:/Users/.../cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src/Eigen
-- CPM: Adding package PMP@3.0.0 (3.0.0)
-- Using Win32 for window creation
CMake Error at cmake-build-debug/_deps/pmp-src/cmake/FindEigen3.cmake:39 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):

    C:/Users/.../cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h


Why Win32? I'm on a 64 bit machine.
The path C:/Users/.../cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src/Eigen/**Eigen**/src/Core/util/Macros.h is indeed wrong. I don't know why the Eigen is repeated twice in the path eigen-src/Eigen/Eigen.


only use CPMAddPackage to get eigen if the target eigen doesn't already exist ?!

@AhmedAEK But then I depend on eigen that is delievered with the PMP. Is that really smart & robust?

Eigen doesn't really get that many updates, so you are likely safe for a few years., otherwise you need to fork that library and modify it.

The CMakeLists.txt for pmp-library contains this snippet:
if(NOT DEFINED EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/eigen-3.4.0")
endif()
find_package(Eigen3 3.4.0 REQUIRED)

If you set this variable in your CPMAddPackage call, pmp-library will use your copy of eigen instead of shipping its own.
The other error stems from PMP defining an eigen target as part of its example suite. You can set PMP_BUILD_EXAMPLES to NO to fix that.
The final error is due to PMP v3.0.0 setting GLFW_SOURCE_DIR to override a variable that GLFW uses internally. In the main branch you will see it actually defines GLFW_SOURCE_DIR_INTERNAL to avoid conflicting.

This helped me move forward, but I get some path-related problems. I've edited my OP.

@skrat You should leave off the final Eigen when you set EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR. As for the other remark, win32 is just the name of the Windows API, it has no bearing on 32 bits vs 64 bits.

I tried it but then I get: CMake Error at cmake-build-debug/_deps/pmp-src/examples/CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):   add_executable cannot create target "eigen" because another target with the   same name already exists.  The existing target is an interface library   created in source directory   "C:/Users/.../cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src".
Which is a CMake in the examples, see this snippet

Ah. That is silly. You can turn off PMP_BUILD_EXAMPLES then. Consider turning off PMP_BUILD_DOCS and PMP_BUILD_TESTS as well.

This seems to be a never ending story. Cannot find source file: external/glfw-3.3.8/include/GLFW/glfw3.h. This now reads to me I will have to manually install all PMP dependencies.

This might be because PMP sets GLFW_SOURCE_DIR, which is what GLFW also uses to refer to its own directory. By contrast, the main branch of PMP uses GLFW_SOURCE_DIR_INTERNAL to avoid stomping on that variable.

If that solves it for you, I suggest you raise an issue on the PMP project that v3.0.0 does not compile out of the box. Or a pull request ;)

Actually, I don't need the OpenGL and other visuals-related stuff that depend on glfw. So I could solve all of this by simply adding PMP_BUILD_VIS OFF to the CPMAddPackage.
